# Input validation for JOptionPane. How would I make sure the input is a double?

Tags: java

> how could you check the input is a double

```
    radius=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the circle?"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not a `double`. Catch the `exception` if you want to do something with it.

That can be done lke this:

```
public void parse() {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the radius of the circle?"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //do something with the input here
        nfe.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)